# How can a non US citizen to get an ITIN and a foreign tax identifier

Tags: united-states, income-tax, itin

I am a non US citizen and it's bean a while that I have subscribed to compeete on an artificial inteligence competition, however when I was reading the [wiki](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/CompetitionClosingProcess.WinnersPerspective) I found that to claim the price a non Us tax payer have to fill a Form W-8BEN,

However in this form they were asking to fill an SSN or ITIN also a foreign tax identifier.

Is it required to fill those two identifiers? if so how can a non US citizen to get those identifiers? is there any specific procedure to do that?

Comment: You don’t have to get ITIN to fill a W8-BEN. I never had problems at leaving the `8.` field blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official guidance is here: [US Governent web site](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/iw8ben).

If you don't have a US tax payer number, then leave box 5 blank.  If **your** government issues an equivalent tax payer number, then put that in box 6 instead.